# Ipv6 not reachable from outside of the network [CENTOS8 + Fritz.Box]

Tags: centos, ipv6

I am using CentOs 8. This is my ifconfig:

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether dc:a6:32:b7:68:6b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 92811  bytes 18351587 (17.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 73439  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17228  bytes 6060848 (5.7 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 23  bytes 2563 (2.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23  bytes 2563 (2.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.113  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 2001:16b8:2ad6:8e00:749e:eeb5:cad4:3ff8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::6203:7858:3288:57d1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:b7:68:6c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 9329  bytes 3579837 (3.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 3449  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9103  bytes 6809912 (6.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And this is my ip a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:b7:68:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:b7:68:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.113/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 863042sec preferred_lft 863042sec
    inet6 2001:16b8:2ad6:8e00:749e:eeb5:cad4:3ff8/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 6695sec preferred_lft 3095sec
    inet6 fe80::6203:7858:3288:57d1/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I opened all needed ports on router (fritz.box) and set default ipv6 interface id `749e:eeb5:cad4:3ff8`
When I ping `fe80::6203:7858:3288:57d1` (local ipv6 ip) from another device I get information, but when I ping `2001:16b8:2ad6:8e00:749e:eeb5:cad4:3ff8` - which should be a public IP, I don't get any information in return. My firewall is off and I IPV6 is enabled.

Can someone please point me in right direction? Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

you have to allow Ping6 in the firewall rules for the host in question.
I use a Fritz!Box 7490 (Internet/Freigaben -> Host)

ICMP does not use ports.
you don't have to set an interface ID.

if you choose a host to edit firewall rules the FB shows you the interface ID of this host. so you can check that you add rules for the right host. the "global dynamic mngtmpaddr" IPv6 address is the one you can ping from outside. at least if there is no firewall rule on that host blocking "icmp echo requests" -> use firewall-cmd --list-all and check "icmp-blocks:"

HTH